# Can't pass more than two arguments to a route

Tags: laravel

I have a route that requires four arguments to be used in the Resource controller's create method. However, whenever I try to pass more than two, in any combination, I get "Missing required parameters".

I've tried both passing them as an array of arguments with route(), or constructing the url directly with same result. If test it by dropping down to any two arguments defined for the route in web.php it works just fine (for both route() and direct url).

I've looked but I can't find anything on a max on the number of arguments. But at the same time I don't understand why it takes 2 arguments fine, but balks at a single more.

The defined route

```
Route::get('formicare/{user_slug}/{taskable_name}/{taskable_slug}/tasks/create/{action_name}', 'TaskController@create')->name('tasks.create');
Route::resource('formicare/tasks', 'TaskController', ['except' => ['create']]);
```

The url in the blade with route()

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('tasks.create', ['user_slug' => $user->slug, 'taskable_name' => 'colonies', 'taskable_slug' => $colony->slug, 'action_name' => 'give_meal']) }}">
   Meals
</a>
```

The url in the route written out

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/formicare/{{$user->slug}}/colonies/{{$colony->slug}}/tasks/create/give_meal">
   Meals 
</a>
```

Both of which give the error

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: tasks.create] [URI: formicare/{user_slug}/{taskable_name}/{taskable_slug}/tasks/create/{action_name}]. (View: C:\laragon\www\antheap\resources\views\colonies\show.blade.php)
```

The controller (empty for testing, but I don't think the problem is here)

```
 public function create($user_slug, $taskable_name, $taskable_slug, $action_name)
    {
        dd('halt'); 
    }
```

However, if I do this with the fewer arguments both versions work will send me to the controller method just fine (of course after removing the redundant arguments in the route() version) for the reduced arguments). And I can switch between any two of the four arguments, but whenever I try to add a third, it breaks.

```
Route::get('formicare/{user_slug}/colonies/{taskable_slug}/tasks/create/give_meal', 'TaskController@create')->name('tasks.create');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not Send the request to the Controller so for testing purpose put a question mark after arguments to make it optional like below :

```
Route::get('formicare/{user_slug?}/{taskable_name?}/{taskable_slug?}/tasks/create/{action_name?}', 'TaskController@create')->name('tasks.create');
```

and then in your controller :

```
 public function create($user_slug = null, $taskable_name = null, $taskable_slug, $action_name = null)
{
    dd('$user_slug'); 
    dd('$taskable_name'); 
    dd('$action_name'); 
}
```

Try the Above DD one by one to See Which of your Requests has results and which returns null that causes that error then you can work on it better .

Comment: I've done this (though changed the dd() to show all variables), and it's working now, passing all 4 arguments just fine. However, after removing all '?' from the route it's still working fine. And removing the'= null' from the method and it's STILL working fine. In fact I put back my old lines of code and it suddenly works like it's supposed to. WTF?! Thanks a million though!

Comment: @Stroomschok happy to help Happy coding :)

Comment: It's so weird. I just had the same problem again! I put all the "?' and '= null' back and it showed all 4 arguments being passed just fine. Graaargh!

Comment: But what happen when u remove the ? and = null again same error about missing the required argument ??